# Why we need double check lock while designing singleton pattern in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, synchronization, singleton

Why we need to check null before and after the lock acquition ?
Once , we acquired the lock , no thread can own the lock then why not null check is required before the synchronization block?

```
public class DclSingleton {
    private static volatile DclSingleton instance;
    public static DclSingleton getInstance() {
        **if (instance == null) {**
            synchronized (DclSingleton .class) {
                **if (instance == null) {**
                    instance = new DclSingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // private constructor and other methods...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine next scenario:

1. Thread 1 check `instance == null` and find this condition true.
2. Thread 2 check `instance == null` and find this condition true.
3. Thread 1 acquire lock.
4. Thread 2 attempt to acquire lock, it is already acquired so Thread 2 waits.
5. Thread 1 initialize `instance = new DclSingleton()`.
6. Thread 1 release lock.
7. Thread 2 acquire lock.
8. Thread 2 initialize `instance = new DclSingleton()`. **We have double initialization**.

Answer (score 2):

You check for `null` twice because:

1. If you do not check before synchronizing on `DclSingleton.class`, then every call would be synchronized, which could be slow (imagine using the singleton instance very frequently).
2. If you do not check for `null` *inside* the `synchronized` block, there is a chance that multiple threads do the first check without having the chance to lock the object yet, and you would re-create the instance.

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation why you need a double `null` check, have a look at the already given answers.

Another way for safely initializing a singleton instance is the *static holder pattern* which would be implememted like this:

```
public class DclSingleton {

    public static DclSingleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private static class Holder {
        private static final DclSingleton INSTANCE = new DclSingleton();
     }
}
```

The JVM initializes classes already in a thread safe way, so even if 2 Threads access `getInstance()` at the same time, the JVM will initialize the `Holder` class only once and thus you have proper initialization.

Also the `Holder` class will be loaded lazily, so it will be initialized only when it is the first time referenced. e.g when `getInstance()` is the first time called

Comment: While it will work in practice. There is no guarantee of laziness in Java spec.

Comment: @Line you right. I remember there was JVM with eager class initialization, but it was before 1.5 spec. Oldest spec I was able to find is 1.6 so I can't tell for sure was this constraint added later or just my memory plays with me:)